# how to write bind method in play framework for 2 interfaces having same class implementations?

Tags: playframework, guice, implementedby

this is my first interface service class having two methods

```java
package services;//this is my service interface class
import com.google.inject.ImplementedBy;
import dtos.MainDTO;
@ImplementedBy(UserServiceImpl.class)
public interface UserService {

    MainDTO getUserDetaile(Integer userId); 

    MainDTO getAllUserDetails();
}
```

this is my second interface service class having two DAO query methods

```java
package services;//this is my DAO interface class
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;

public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<Users, Long> {

    @Query("select userId,firstName from Users where userId =:userId")
    public List<Object[]> getUserDetails(@Param("userId") Integer userId);

    @Query("select userId,firstName from Users")
    public List<Object[]> getAllUserDetails();
}
```

And this is the class implementation class for above two interfaces.
In 1st interface i annotated with `@Implementedby` annotation and its working fine. But for 2nd interface what needs to be added?

```java
package services;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import dtos.MainDTO;
import dtos.UserDTO;

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    private  UserRepository userRepository;

    @Inject
    public UserServiceImpl(UserRepository userRepository){
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public  MainDTO getUserDetaile(Integer userId){
        //method implementaion goes here
    }
    @Override
    public MainDTO getAllUserDetails() {

        //method implementaion goes here
}
```

Facing a problem like

[image]

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/tpsvO.jpg this is my issue what i was faceing

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to have `guice-repository` library added [here it is](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.guice-repository/guice-repository/2.1.0).

In your module, you need to install repositories like the following

```
@Override
protected void configure() {
    //Repository classes auto-scanned by package name
   install(new ScanningJpaRepositoryModule(repositoriesBasePackageName, persistenceUnitName));
}
```

Once you have the repos scanned, you can inject your interfaces directly into your service or where you want.

Full details can be found [here](http://cleancodejava.com/guice-repository-simple-example/).

The valid constructor for a Play module will be like the following.

```
public YourModule(Environment environment, Configuration configuration) {
        this.environment = environment;
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }
```

Comment: first of all thank you friend. i follow what u said .but now i show issue like no valid constructors Module [Module] cannot be instantiated.

Comment: @HaiPandu I have updated the answer with a valid constructor for the Play module.